# jQuery 1.9.x plugin sudoSlider how to get information from selector and pass to options during object's creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to put some data into DIV and then set slideCount option based on that value during creation of new object.

HTML looks like below:

```
<div class="filter-slider" data-slidecount="5"></div>
```

My JS:

```
var sudoSlider = $(".filter-slider").sudoSlider({
    slideCount: this.selector.data('slidecount') || 2,
    continuous:true,
    controlsFade: false,
    speed: 500
});
```

I tried to use `this.selector`, `$(this)` and so on, however since jQuery 1.9  `this.selector` doesn't work anymore. How should I get reference to the selector in such situation?